# Remove the "All" button from the menu, its content, and display the first category as a summary

Tags: wordpress

I hope you're doing well. I have recently created a website with a menu that includes three links: "All" and several categories. However, I would like to remove the "All" button from the menu, along with its content. Instead, I want to display a summary of the first category on the homepage.

I have tried searching through the WordPress documentation for a solution, but I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer. Additionally, I would prefer not to specify the category name in the code; I want it to automatically select and display the first category without explicitly mentioning it.
CODE WORDPRESS - THEME OWL

```
 <?php if($tpl == "layout1") : ?>
            <div class="mix col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 single-menu <?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $term_list));?>" data-bound>
                  <div class="single-menu-details">
                    <div class="food-menu-img">
                    <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' )[0]; ?>" class="menu-popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail("jws-imge-crop-thumbnail-menutoday");?>
                    </a>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="food-menu-details">
                        <h3>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>                                                           <?php $prix = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'tb_menutoday_price',true);                                if($prix){                                      echo "<span class='menu-price'>$prix</span>";       }                               else{                               echo  "";       }                           ?>                      
                        </h3>                       
                        <?php 
                            the_content();
                         ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>       
            </div>
            <?php endif;  ?>
            <?php if($tpl == "layout2") : ?>
            <div class="mix col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 single-menu <?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $term_list));?>" data-bound>
                  <div class="single-menu-details">
                    <div class="food-menu-img">
                        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' )[0]; ?>" class="menu-popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail("jws-imge-crop-thumbnail-menutoday-two");?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="food-menu-details">
                        <h4>
                            <?php the_title();                          ?>
                        </h4>                           <?php  the_excerpt();                         ?>                        <?php                             the_content();                          ?>                         
                        <p class="menu-price"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'tb_menutoday_price',true); ?></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>       
            </div>
            <?php endif;  ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    return ob_get_clean();

}

if(function_exists('insert_shortcode')) { insert_shortcode('menu_today_filter', 'jwsthemes_menu_filter_func');}
```

If any of you have encountered a similar situation or have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

I tried searching within WP Query, Array Filter. I also attempted using apply_filters, but it doesn't seem to be working, or perhaps I'm not using it correctly.